# How to replace Map with null if map key from (key,struct) is null in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to replace map with null if key is null in spark dataframe.

DF.printSchema

```
-- sku_id: string (nullable = true) 
-- sku_images: map (nullable = true)  
-- key: string  
-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true) 
-- image_id: string (nullable = true)  
-- image_name: string (nullable = true)  
-- image_path: string (nullable = true)


11111111|Map(null -> [null,null,null])
22222222|Map(null -> [null,null,null])
33333333|Map(largeImage_1 -> [111,222,test data])
```

expected output :-

```
11111111|null
22222222|null
33333333|Map(largeImage_1 -> [111,222,loading test data])
```

Thanks,

Comment: Apache Spark does not support `null` keys for `MapType` objects so it just not possible to get there. If anything, you can have literal string `"null"` there. Please post a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

you can't have a `null` as key for a map, so I guess you have a `"null"` as key. You can set those maps to `null` with the following udf:

```
val mapSchema = DF.schema.find(_.name=="sku_images").get.dataType
val nullifyMap = udf((m: Map[String, Row]) => if (m.keySet.contains("null")) null else m, mapSchema)

val newDF = DF
  .withColumn("sku_images",  nullifyMap($"sku_images"))
```